# making a virtualized list with a separate file in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-virtualized

I created a to do list app in app.js and a virtualized list in VirtualizedList.js but none of the virtualized list code is displaying although I imported it into app.js properly.

Here is the VirtualizedList.js code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, VirtualizedList, StyleSheet, Text, 
StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [];

const getItem = (data, index) => ({
  id: Math.random().toString(12).substring(0),
  title: `Item ${index+1}`
});

const getItemCount = (data) => 50;

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
   );

const App = () => {
  return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
        data={DATA}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}
        getItemCount={getItemCount}
        getItem={getItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
   marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
   marginVertical: 7,
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    padding: 20,
 },
  title: {
   fontSize: 25,
  },
});

export default App;
```

This is how I imported VirtualizedList into app.js:
import VirtualizedList from '/Users/myname/Applications/todo-
app/src/components/VirtualizedList';

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would export default your list in VirtualizedList.js and you would import them in your App.js (renderer) as a normal object. But I would have to see the code to be sure

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve that problem. But now none of my virtualized.js code is showing up when I run app.js

Comment: Your data here is DATA. Which is an empty list that you defined yourself. It shouldn’t render anything. I think you want your data to be the data from your list